# Symfony Production deployment has different css than debug

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony 2.8 but I don't think it matters for this question.

My production deployment is displaying a different version of the stylesheet than from debug environment.

What do I need to do to align production with debug?

Comment: have you run php app/console assets:install
php app/console assetic:dump after deployment?

Comment: I did run the assets install and assetic dump. Didn't make a difference. Thanks for asking!

Comment: You can refer to your own specific version, [see](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-version).

Comment: I thought about what Vladimir said about my own specific version.  That doesn't work for me because as far as I know the css file being pointed to  is the same file.  So, there is no version tag to add.  I also noticed that some of the editing I have done is not being included too.  This is just my lack of understanding how symfony is handling the dev vs prod config.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was when running the following command:

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

I would get a

> ERROR 522 Validation failed : no DTD found

for one of my translations messages xliff

I removed that and ran the command again and then ran the server and my css was correctly being utilized.